# ERR_CONNECTION_RESET *only* when making asynchronous calls to db using ajax - CakePHP

Tags: php, sql-server, ajax, cakephp, pdo

I'm working on a very simple utility using CakePHP 2.4.6 and PHP 5.4.16 (a full breakdown of my environment is below). The database is a legacy MS SQL database hosted on AWS.  I was able to get everything involving PDO configured in such a way that the app is connecting to the database successfully and both pulling and updating records.

My main controller presents a view to the user containing relevant records pulled from the database.  Each record has a simple associated form with a single checkbox that allows the user to update that record.  When the user ticks the checkbox, I use ajax to make a call to a method on a *separate* controller, which updates that record in the db and returns the result.

Here's the problem I'm running into: If I tick a bunch of boxes in quick succession, everything works fine--all of the records are updated successfully.  However, if I pause between ticking boxes (10 seconds, or so) *every other update fails* with `net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET`. Nothing is recorded in `error.log`.  So I tick one box, ajax fires, record is updated; pause; tick another box, ajax fires, controller returns an error; pause; tick another box, ajax fires, record is updated, etc.

I confirmed that the error is related to the app trying to connect to the database, as everything works fine if I remove all database operations from the controller method and just return some arbitrary value to the ajax call.  My (uneducated) guess is that I'm running into some sort of problem with duplicate/parallel connections to the database.  Thus whenever a duplicate connection is attempted, the connection is reset, which means that the next time a connection is attempted the connection is successful, and so on.  I haven't posted any code because I'm really not sure where to begin trying to fix this.  As far as I can tell everything is working in my code; I don't know if this is a problem with the CakePHP framework itself, or my database configuration, or PDO's driver setup, or something else I'm missing.  Let me know if the specific code would be helpful, and thanks in advance for any help!

My environment:

- Windows 8
- WampServer 2.4 x86
- Apache 2.4.4
- CakePHP 2.4.6
- PHP 5.4.16
- Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Redistributable Package x86
- Microsoft SQL Server 2008 Native Client
- Microsoft ODBC Driver 11
- Microsoft SQLSRV driver 3.0 (specifically php_pdo_sqlsrv_54_ts.dll)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've the same problem but not necessarily with AJAX call, just on load page, sending form, etc...

- Windows 10
- XAMPP 5.6.21-0
- PHP 5.6.21
- CakePHP 2.8.5
- Microsoft SQL Server 2012
- Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio
- Microsoft SQLSRV driver 3.2
- php_pdo_sqlsrv_56_ts.dll
- Microsoft ODBC Driver 11

EDIT : AND PROBLEM SOLVED !
in app/Config/database.php set 'persistent' to false

```
public $default = array(
    'datasource' => 'Database/Sqlserver',
    'persistent' => false,
    'database' => 'YOURDB',
);
```